# Brew install qt does not work on macOS Sierra

Tags: homebrew

I upgraded my mac to Sierra and I can't install qt. I wrote "brew install qt" and I received the message below. Do you have any recommendations?

"This formula either does not compile or function as expected on macOS
versions newer than El Capitan due to an upstream incompatibility.
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build."

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I was able to sucessfully work around this on a fresh install of Sierra this evening.

It looks like qt.rb will execute just fine on MacOS Sierra, you just need to remove the Maximum OS requirement entry to allow it to run.

This is what was required on my machine.

```
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/qt.rb
```

Comment out line 36 as follows

```
#depends_on MaximumMacOSRequirement => :el_capitan
```

I am curious if this works for others.

Thanks

Comment: This helped me run `brew install qt` on Sierra but the install still fails with `make: *** [sub-plugins-make_default-ordered] Error 2`. Please let me know if you've overcome this

Comment: like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: It devoured 100% of my RAM for 15 mins and then I cancelled it. Used `brew install qt5` instead and it worked fine.

Comment: This also worked with apple-gcc42 in MacOS Sierra. The message was `apple-gcc42: This formula either does not compile or function as expected on macOS versions newer than Mavericks due to an upstream incompatibility` and just commenting the depends_on line in the file `/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/apple-gcc42.rb` did the trick. Thanks!!

Answer (score 28):

if you really need qt4, you can try

> brew install cartr/qt4/qt

Comment: installed for me too, MBP & Sierra 10.12.2.. Fingers crossed it works with the py I just inherited.

Answer (score 11):

Searching with

```
brew search qt
```

you can see there is a QT5

```
brew install qt5
```

According to https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/1957#issuecomment-225806023 there will be no support for qt(4)

Comment: qt5: A full installation of Xcode.app is required to compile this software.

Answer (score 3):

Qt4 is not supported anymore; users should upgrade to Qt5. Homebrew backported a fix for 10.11 but doesn’t intend to maintain this forever. There’s currently a [pull-request that may fix that](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/5216). You’ll have to wait for it to be merged if you want to install Qt4 with Homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

install qt4

**Please note:** Qt4 is unsupported by its creators, so there are likely security/usability problems with it that will never be resolved. If you can, please consider migrating your projects to Qt5.

resource : https://github.com/cartr/homebrew-qt4

```
brew tap cartr/qt4
brew tap-pin cartr/qt4
brew install qt
```