# How to install qt4 with home-brew

Tags: qt, homebrew

I'm trying to install LabelImg, but in order to do so I need to install qt4 first because I'm using python 2. All the guides I find tell me to do

```
brew install qt qt4
```

But I just get "Error: No formulae found in taps." I also tried

```
brew install cartr/qt4/qt
```

But when I went to build LabelImg I get

```
make: *** [qt4py2] Error 1
```

I am on the latest version of OSX and I have tried the alternative methods of installing Qt, it seems like it is installed properly, but I can't use it to make anything

Comment: What version of OSX are you currently running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Brew install qt does not work on macOS Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39690404/brew-install-qt-does-not-work-on-macos-sierra)

Comment: @darol100 I am using. 10.13.4

Answer (score 15):

> This Homebrew tap allows you to install Qt4 (and various packages that
>   depend on it) on macOS Sierra and newer. You can install it like this:
>
> ```
> brew tap cartr/qt4
> brew tap-pin cartr/qt4
> brew install qt@4
> ```

[Source](https://github.com/cartr/homebrew-qt4)

Comment: I ran make qt4py2 and it still gave me the same thing after doing all of the above steps

Comment: +1. FWIW, on High Sierra, for the second command I got `Error: Unknown command: tap-pin`, but the first and third commands appeared to be successful.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

> brew install cartr/qt4/pyqt@4

Comment: On OSX, you might also need to run `brew install openssl@1.0` see https://github.com/cartr/homebrew-qt4/issues/67